# # of items in review queue is incorrect

Tags: bug, review

I have [suggested an edit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1778) to a question but when I look at the [stats page for the suggested edits queue](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) it says there are 0 items that need review. I also have 5 tag wiki edits pending. But still it says 0 needs review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review queue descriptions are a bit brief, which leads to a lot of confusion.  The "items that need review" leave off from the description "that you can perform".  The number doesn't reflect the total contents of the queue, just the number available for you to review.  Some examples of what is excluded from the count you see:

- Your own posts or edits (you can't review your own stuff).
- Things you have already reviewed that still require additional reviews by others.

Comment: Makes sense but when I go to the `/review` page on Stack overflow and many other sites I can view that there are items in all queues even ones I do not have access to.

Comment: @Ethan, interesting.  It's been a while since I worked the review queues (generally do what's needed when stuff appears on the main page), and it's been a while since I did content curation on sites where I don't have sufficient rep for all of the queues. That last bullet was my recollection of how the queues used to work.  It's also possible that there are some site-to-site variations.  I'll delete the last bullet, since it looks like it may not be accurate.  thanks for the feedback.